# How to extract values from tuple in Python?

Tags: python, regex, datetime

Hello I have the following;

```
A =
((248500353L,
  11,
  '4',
  '248741302',
  633,
  7321L,
  7321L,
  'EAD4083003',
  0,
  datetime.datetime(2011, 4, 19, 23, 0, 42),
  datetime.datetime(2011, 4, 19, 23, 1, 39)),)
```

I want to extract all the values between commas and keep the date format. What I am doing is the following:

```
An =  re.findall(r'\d+', str(A))
```

that return all the integers that are present in A, but in this way I loose  the information regarding the date format. Any suggestion?

Comment: I suppose the first question is where did you get the format from in the first place, and could you have something more useful instead?

Comment: I did not understand your question. I would like to extract all the values between commas, keeping the date format of the last two entries.

Comment: My question is **why are you trying to parse that?** You appear to have the string form of some Python objects - where did it come from? Can you get the actual objects? Or arrange a more easily parseable format? What is the purpose of this task? Also, please note that your title is meaningless.

Comment: This looks like a one-element tuple containing a perfectly usable tuple of your data. Do you know how to index or unpack a tuple?

Comment: Is your source data text (or a file containing text) in this format?

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that the comma and middle paren on the last line (the `),` in `datetime.datetime(2011, 4, 19, 23, 1, 39)),)` ) look like they need to be swapped too.

Comment: Yes I have access directly to the tuple and it makes the life easier!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been stated `A` is already a Python tuple, there is no need to convert it into a string first and attempt to parse using a regular expression.

If you are trying to write this data to a CSV file, the tuple can be written directly as follows:

```
import datetime 
import csv

A = ((248500353L,
    11,
    '4',
    '248741302',
    633,
    7321L,
    7321L,
    'EAD4083003',
    0,
    datetime.datetime(2011, 4, 19, 23, 0, 42),
    datetime.datetime(2011, 4, 19, 23, 1, 39)),)

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:  
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(A[0])
```

This would give you an output file looking like:

```
248500353,11,4,248741302,633,7321,7321,EAD4083003,0,2011-04-19 23:00:42,2011-04-19 23:01:39
```

In this case, these is no need to first try and extract all of the entries. If you need finer control over the date format, then this could easily be added. Here it uses the default conversion to a string format.

It does though assume that you wish to output all of the fields.